# Cannot play video recorder by GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, m4v

I am using `GPUImage` library to record a video to a file on filesystem. I save it as m4v file. This is the code I'm using:

```
    NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:recordingDestination];
    unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

    movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(1280.0, 720.0)];
    [videoCameraFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

    movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
    movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
    [movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

    [movieWriter startRecording];
    [movieFile startProcessing];

    [movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
        [videoCameraFilter removeTarget:movieWriter];
        [movieWriter finishRecording];
    }];
```

This records a m4v video. I then try to play it with `MPMoviePlayerController`:

```
    NSString *videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"], [libraryFiles objectAtIndex:selectedCell]];
    NSLog(videoPath);
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:videoPath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDonePressed) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    [moviePlayer play];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

However, the player just starts buffering and nothing happens. The video doesn't start playing. The player is just buffering forever. The app doesn't crash and there are no warnings in the console, so I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: have you checked the video is there in the saved destination? download  and play it on your pc to make sure that video is not corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at a couple of things that don't look right.

First off you're writing directly to `NSHomeDirectory` which returns the application directory that is however not writeable (see [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSHomeDirectory)).
Either write to the `Documents` folder or the `Library/Caches` folder instead.

Secondly I don't see how `videoCameraFilter` is defined. You need to make sure to add it as a target of `movieFile`

```
GPUImageMovie *movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pathToMovie = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filtered-movie.m4v"];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(1920.0, 1080.0)];
GPUImageBoxBlurFilter * videoCameraFilter = [[GPUImageBoxBlurFilter alloc] init]; // just a random filter...
videoCameraFilter.blurSize = 2.0;
[movieFile addTarget:videoCameraFilter];
[videoCameraFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

[movieWriter startRecording];
[movieFile startProcessing];

__weak GPUImageMovieWriter *weakMoviewWriter = movieWriter;
[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    [movieFile removeTarget:weakMoviewWriter];
    [weakMoviewWriter finishRecording];
}];
```

* EDIT:

Did you try yo making `moviePlayer` a property/ivar as @SAMIR RATHOD suggested? The fact that the moviePlayer stays there buffering endlessly is most probably caused because it's not being retained.

add a property to your viewController's interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

and instantiate your `MPMoviewPlayerController`:

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

Comment: No, I am writing to Documents directory. I am then trying to play the video AFTER I record it. I know the video is proper, because if I just open it from camera roll, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

First Check videoPath it display proper path or not?

.h File

```
   MPMoviePlayerController*     player
```

.m
       @synthesize player;

```
    -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
            [super viewWillAppear:animated];

           player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoPath]];
           player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
           player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
           player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 45, 320, 400);
           player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
           [player prepareToPlay];
           [self.view addSubview:player.view];
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

           [player play];
    }

    #pragma mark MoviPlayer Method

    - (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
            MPMoviePlayerController *player1 = [aNotification object];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player1];
            [player stop];
            [player1.view removeFromSuperview];

            player1 = nil;
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    -(void) dealloc {
            [player release];
            [super dealloc];
    }
```